# How to stop Java WatchService when is waiting for key?

Tags: java, multithreading, watchservice

I'm trying to stop my thread where `WatchService` is working. But how to do that? My `WatchService` waiting for new update in folder there:

```
key = watchService.take();
```

I start my Thread there:

```
private void startButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        stateLabel.setText("monitoring...");

        try {
            watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        watchThread = new WatchThread(watchService, key);
        Thread t = new Thread(watchThread);
        t.start();

    }
```

My trying to stop:

```
private void stopButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     try {
        if (watchService!=null) {
            key.cancel();
            watchService.close();
        }
     } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

When I try to execute the stop, I get `NullPointerException` in key.
When I'm just closing watchService with `watchService.close()`, I get another exception: `ClosedWatchServiceException`.

How to close a `WatchService` without any exceptions? 
Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Please show us the exception you are getting.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis update my question

Comment: Try printing `key` right before the `key.cancel()` line, to make sure `key` is not null.

Comment: Set `key` to a non-null value before making the user interface visible, to prevent the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exceptions you are getting are happening because you aren't controlling your UI events.

A [`ClosedWatchServiceException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/ClosedWatchServiceException.html) occurs when you try to use a `WatchService` whose `close()` method has been called. So you are probably calling `watchService.take()` or some other `WatchService` method after calling `close()`. It might happen that the `take()` method unblocks after you close the `WatchService` and immediately throws the `Exception`.

You get a `NullPointerException` with `key` because you are trying to call `cancel()` on the instance before having initialized it. I'm guessing it's declared somewhere in your class as

```
private WatchKey key;
```

By default, instance reference type variables are initialized to `null`. If your execution never takes you through

```
key = watchService.take();
```

then `key` will remain `null`.